# C# Reflection performance comparison when invoking class with parameter

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, linq-expressions

I have heard a lot about Linq Expression performance. But wasn't able to check it myself.
Please take a look on the next .NET Core app example:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var classType = Type.GetType("ConsoleApp1.TestClass");
            var classConstructor = classType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });

            //var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
            //var newExpression = Expression.New(classConstructor, param);
            //LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(newExpression, param);
            //var compiled = lambda.Compile();
            //var instance = compiled.DynamicInvoke("test");

            //var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType, "test");

            //var instance = classConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { "test" });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass(string param)
        {

        }
    }
```

When I am running this code with Expression version uncommented then code works 10 times slower.
Please advice what could be wrong or it is as expected.

Comment: How many times dou you execute the instantiation? You should keep both `classConstructor ` and `compiled` variables and then do a warm-up (calling all three a few times) and then start your benchmark

Comment: It all depends on what you "heard a lot about Linq Expression performance"... Usually it is "don't use reflection to call something million times, compile expression once and use it million times, or use `dynamic` to cache reflection for you, or at least cache most of the reflection calls"... Comparing single reflection call to creation of an expression is absolutely not expected to show benefits...

Comment: What I mean is, the lambda expression compilation should be done once and the compiled expression should be stored. The Reflection constructor retrieval also must take place once and should be stored. Then, and only then can you run 
a compiled lambda / ConstructorInfo instantiation comparison benchmark.

Comment: `DynamicInvoke` is even worse than reflection. Compiled expression makes sense when it is compiled to strongly typed delegate and called with `Invoke`.

Comment: If we are going to compile it once and run it millions of times, how about compiling with Roslyn (or CodeDom) a concrete class which implements an interface to create the instance? (strongly typed too). Nothing can beat that I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple benchmark shows interesting results. Durations are in milliseconds.

I just wanted to share the results I got. Seems like DynamicInvoke really has a big overhead (as @ivan-stoev pointed out)

I will add the results for both the `.Invoke` solution with a strongly typed lambda and the Roslyn compiled concrete class implementing a simple interface for instantiation.

`ConstructorInfo` is cached, and so is the compiled lambda expression.

For 10 million iterations each: (100 million instantiations for each method)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark Results:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    Activator           Constructor         Compiled Lambda
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Totals :            8121.2488           3067.6226           9353.8141


Average:            0.00081212488       0.00030676226       0.00093538141


Maximum:            922.5987            450.7662            1046.3734


Minimum:            0                   0                   0


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```